# don' work prepSentinel with sentinel 1 data

Tags: r, gis, sentinel, satellite-image, sentinel1

I 'm new to using R...i'm trying to pre-process sentinel 1 data; I am using a packages `getSpatialData` (https://rdrr.io/github/16EAGLE/getSpatialData/man/getSpatialData-package.html). I downloaded the images and it works. But, when I try to use the function `prepSentinel` I get out 
this error message:

```
    Preparing 'C:....get_data/Sentinel- 
    1//S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190120T170653_20190120T170720_025564_02D624_98F9.zip'...
    Error: Selected tiles are not contained within dataset.
```

I have followed this code (is simple copied from GitHub...)

```
    ## Define time range and platform
    time_range <-  c("2019-01-08", "2019-01-21")
    platform <- "Sentinel-1"

   ## set login credentials and an archive directory
   login_CopHub(username = "------", password = '------') #asks for password or define 'password'
   #set_archive("/path/to/archive/")
   set_archive('C:/Users/mfrig/Desktop/tesi/ISAT_nuovo')

   ## Use getSentinel_query to search for data (using the session AOI)
   records <- getSentinel_query(time_range = time_range, platform = platform)

   ## Get an overview of the records
   View(records) #get an overview about the search records
   colnames(records) #see all available filter attributes
   unique(records$producttype) #use one of the, e.g. to see available processing levels


   ## Filter the records
   records_filtered <- records[which(records$producttype == "GRD"),] #filter by Level
   #records_filtered <- records_filtered[as.numeric(records_filtered$cloudcoverpercentage) <= 100, ] 
   #filter by clouds
   View(records_filtered)


   ## Download some datasets
   datasets <- getSentinel_data(records [c(1),])

   # Make them ready to use
   datasets_prep <- prepSentinel(datasets, format = "tiff")
```

I have tried the function `prepSentinel` with Sentinel 2 data and it works, but when I downloaded Sentinel 1 data not.
any advice?

thanks a lot

Comment: This issue has been also raised on GitHub: https://github.com/16EAGLE/getSpatialData/issues/55, and I explain my view of the problem here: https://github.com/16EAGLE/getSpatialData/issues/55#issuecomment-625738576

Does anyone know a direction for a solution for this?